# Extract data csv file and write on another file in python

Tags: python, file, csv

I have to write a Python application to read a CSV input file (appsUsage.csv) and generate an output file counting the frequency of the apps usage per user. The first column of the input file contains user id (user_id) and the second column contains the name of the app (app_name).  From appsUsage.csv, I have to count the frequency of apps usage on individual user basis to generate app_Rank, and transform to a new data set named appsIndividualUsage.csv with the following columns: user_id; app_name; app_Rank.

For example if appsUsage.csv has following events

```
a  facebook
a  facebook
a  linkedin
b  google
b  yahoo
b  yahoo
```

Then appsIndividualUsage.csv would be:

```
a  facebook  2;
a  linkedin  1;
b  google  1;
b  yahoo  2;
```

Here is my code that I am struggling with :

```
import csv 
with open("C:\\Users\\anne\\Desktop\\appsUsage.csv", mode='r') as f_in,
open("C:\\Users\\anne\\Desktop\\appsIndividualUsage.csv", mode='w', newline='')
as f_out:
        f_reader = csv.reader(f_in, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
        f_writer = csv.writer(f_out, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
         for line in reader:
             if line is equal then write it in writer and add a row of frequency
```

I totally don't know how to write the last line of my code.

Comment: How about Parsing data from `appsUsage.csv` first store the required data and then create `appsIndividualUsage.csv` and writing data in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Python provides a [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) for doing this. It is a dictionary like object which can be used to count keys added to it. In this case the key for the dictionary is a combination of the user's name and the application.

First read all of the entries in from the input CSV file and count them. Then write the sorted counts to the output CSV file as follows:

```
from collections import Counter    
import csv 

usage_counts = Counter()

with open('appsUsage.csv') as f_in:
    f_reader = csv.reader(f_in, dialect=csv.excel_tab)

    for user, application in f_reader:
        usage_counts[(user, application)] += 1

with open("appsIndividualUsage.csv", mode='w', newline='') as f_out:
    f_writer = csv.writer(f_out, dialect=csv.excel_tab)

    for (user, application), count in sorted(usage_counts.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])):
        f_writer.writerow([user, application, count])
```

This would give you a CSV file as follows:

```
a   facebook    2
a   linkedin    1
b   google  1
b   yahoo   2
```

If you are not allowed to use a `Counter()`, then you would need to use a normal dictionary, and add 1 to any existing key.